# Power Query | Appending refresh-disabled table with refresh-enabled table

Tags: powerquery, powerbi-desktop, m

I hope you can help me out. At least once a week I must refresh a PowerBi report, connected to an Oracle database.

Currently, I'm retrieving 2 million plus records, and logically, it takes an increasingly long time. Let's call this table 0

I had the idea of appending 2 tables, where:

table 0 (current one, 2 milllion records and rising)
`SELECT * FROM DB`

table 1  (1.75 million records, no updates)
`SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.date < TO_DATE('2023-12-01','DD-MM-YYYY')`

table 2  (250k records, and rising)
`SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.date >= TO_DATE('2023-12-01','DD-MM-YYYY')`

My idea is to append both table1 and table 2, allowing the one with most recent records to refresh.

However, after enabling and disabling respectively the tables, and appending them, the consolidated table does not get updated.

I KNOW that I could load both tables into Power Bi desktop, and `UNION()` them. however, there are memory/space issues, not to mention that the report has many formulas and many dependencies to the current "table 0". Therefore, although I would be getting a faster refreshing process, the whole report would have to be overhauled.

Is there a way to effectively paste tables 1 and 2, setting only 2 to update, WITHIN POWER QUERY?